# Anchor a floating div to numerous elements on a page

Tags: css

Whats the best way to position a div at multiple places on a page anchoring the div from the bottom left. It should be able to attach it to any element on the page, using that element as for relative positioning. Its for a tool tip. Each tool tip will have the same width, but depending on text in tooltip, that will determine the height.

Answer (score 0):

you will use absolute positioning , the parent element that it is relative to will be positioned relative

when using absolute positioning to get the element outside of a relative parent use negative value for left and top

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="tooltip"></div>
</div>

.parent{ position: relative;  /*set whatever else */}
.tooltip {position: relative; bottom: -20px; left: -20px; height 20px; width:20px;}
```

just an example of 20px X 20px tooltip that is positioned to the bottom and left of the parent

Comment: what if the parent div is floated. Is this still possible?